# Org-mode logtable Latex export: How to change the "Continued on next page" text (to German)?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am writing a German document in Org-mode and exporting to Latex. To use the longtable environment, I use:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable
|-|-|-|
```

In this way, a long table is exported as expected. For the table cut at any page, the text "Continued on next page" is added at the end of the page (exported by Org mode). Adding German babel does not change the message exported by Org-mode. My question is: How to make Org mode conform to the document language? Otherwise, how can I manually override (change) the message in Org mode export?

What I have:

```
#+Language: de
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{german,longtable}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: The `#+LANGUAGE:` attribute works well for me. See my answer. If this does not work for you please add more information: `emacs-version`, `org-version` and a minimal self-contained example for reconstruction of the problem. Please also test with `emacs -Q` to avoid configuration errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`#+LANGUAGE: de`

at the top of your document or customize the value of the option `org-export-default-language` if you write many documents in German.

See the documentation of [Export Settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html).

Example that works for me with emacs 25.1.1 and **`org-version` 9.0.5**:

```org
#+LANGUAGE: de
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

* LaTeX

#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable
|-------------+--------+---|
| 3.8.3.45754 | 3.9.0. |   |
|-------------+--------+---|
|           1 |      8 |   |
|           2 |      7 |   |
|           3 |      6 |   |
|           4 |      5 |   |
|           5 |      3 |   |
|           6 |      2 |   |
|           7 |      4 |   |
|           8 |     19 |   |
|           9 |     18 | f |
|          10 |     17 |   |
|          11 |     16 |   |
|          12 |     15 |   |
|          13 |     14 |   |
|          14 |     13 |   |
|          15 |     11 |   |
|          16 |     10 |   |
|          17 |      1 |   |
|          18 |     12 |   |
|          19 |      9 |   |
|           1 |      8 |   |
|           2 |      7 |   |
|           3 |      6 |   |
|           4 |      5 |   |
|           5 |      3 |   |
|           6 |      2 |   |
|           7 |      4 |   |
|           8 |     19 |   |
|           9 |     18 | f |
|          10 |     17 |   |
|          11 |     16 |   |
|          12 |     15 |   |
|          13 |     14 |   |
|          14 |     13 |   |
|          15 |     11 |   |
|          16 |     10 |   |
|          17 |      1 |   |
|          18 |     12 |   |
|          19 |      9 |   |
|           1 |      8 |   |
|           2 |      7 |   |
|           3 |      6 |   |
|           4 |      5 |   |
|           5 |      3 |   |
|           6 |      2 |   |
|           7 |      4 |   |
|           8 |     19 |   |
|           9 |     18 | f |
|          10 |     17 |   |
|          11 |     16 |   |
|          12 |     15 |   |
|          13 |     14 |   |
|          14 |     13 |   |
|          15 |     11 |   |
|          16 |     10 |   |
|          17 |      1 |   |
|          18 |     12 |   |
|          19 |      9 |   |
```

Comment: I think he already did this

Comment: @jue It works for me. `org-version` 9.0.5, emacs: 25.1.1

Comment: this did not work for me and the questioner wrote this already in his question. See code at "What I have:" But on the other hand, I only use org-version 8.2.10.

Comment: Addition to above comment: What I get is a german "Inhaltsverzeichnis" but an english "Continued on next page" `#+Language` or `#+LANGUAGE` does not seem to matter.

Comment: @jue Nice that you can reconstruct the problem. Do you have an entry for `"Continued on next page"` in `org-export-dictionary`? In function `org-latex-table-row` is there `(org-latex--translate "Continued from previous page" info)` in it or is `org-latex--translate` missing?

Comment: no not even the string "Continue" is included in this var. So he has to add "Continued on next" and a german translation to this var to teach org-mode.

Comment: @jue Adding `"Continued on next page"` to `org-export-dictionary` only works if `org-latex--translate` is used in `org-latex-table-row`. Could you have a look? Thanks in advance...

Comment: neither `org-latex--translate` nor `org-latex-translate` is included in file `ox-latex.el` which includes function `org-latex-table-row`

Comment: I can't find function `org-latex--translate` at all. But `org-export-dictionary` exists

Comment: I appreciate it guys ... I have Emacs 25.1.50.1 and Org 8.2.10

Comment: The problem is solved by upgrading to Org 9.0.8. Now I have some minor problems from version change. Thanks @jue for your very helpful answer, very educational. I would have to accept the answer of Tobias because the version upgrade solved the problem!

Comment: @Hisham If Jue's answer is "very helpful" for you the right way to honor that is to upvote his answer. Best regards,

Comment: I wish I could... not allowed to upvote yet!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to do it manually.
Execute this code before doing the export:

```
(defun my-latex-filter-continue-string (text backend info)
    "Ensure \"_\" are properly handled in LaTeX export."
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
        (replace-regexp-in-string "Continued on next page" "Weiter auf nächster Seite" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-table-functions
             'my-latex-filter-continue-string)
```

Have A look into [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html) to find more information:

Edit: if you, the reader, has this problem, check your org-version. If you are at version 8.2.10. or lower you have 3 options:

1. Upgrade `org-mode` to version 9.x (9.0.5 has been reported to work)
2. Use the code I gave above, e.g. put it in your `init.el`, then on every export the string will be replaced.
3. enhance the functions involved and update `org-export-dictionary` with the appropriate translation string

Of course my solution can be adapted to similar problems, also for newer org-mode versions. :)

Edit2: Out of curiosity I had a look at the third option.
Sadly the mentioned string is hard coded in function `org-latex-table-row (table-row contents info)` which you can find in file `ox-latex.el`.
To change the output you have to replace the string in the function.

Comment: For new versions of org-mode see Answer from Tobias and the comments there